# Make a form in php that saves information a user gives, and plugs it into a another printable page

Tags: php, webforms, populate

I'm working on a site that gives the users of the site pre-written letters to send to places. All the user has to do is fill out a form and hit continue, then whatever information the user put into the form (like name for example) gets plugged into a pre-written letter on a printable page. A basic example would be if the form asks for **Name** then you hit continue, on the printable page, it would say:

Hi, my name is **Zach**.

I'm using a php based content management system so it should be in php. I know this is a very simple thing to do for those who know how to do it, I unfortunately don't. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: We can't answer this. Show us the code you have, and maybe we can help.

Comment: we can answer this, its a pretty simple answer and we dont need to see his code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have this form:

```
<form action="preview.php" method="POST" >
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="submit" value"Print" />
</form>
```

When you hit submit, the values of all the fields (input in this case, but also textarea, selects, etc) are save to the POST array (or GET if you set method="GET").

You access the POST and GET arrays from the preview.php page (where you want to print the name in this example) with code like this:

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];
?>
<p>Hi, my name is <strong><?=$name?></strong>.</p>
```

Comment: upps! Sorry, I have nearly duplicated the anwser from benhowdle89 letter by letter! Didn't see it.

Comment: This should work perfectly guys, thank you! I'll finish the page with this and probably be back on here if I hit a snag. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

in your first page:

```
<form action="letter.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="personsName"></input>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Then in letter.php do this:

```
<?php
$firstname = $_GET['personsName'];
echo "My Name is" .$firstname;
?>
```

That ok? :)

Comment: This is perfect, as I said in the above answer. Just wanted to comment on both since you both pretty much answered at the same time. Thank you both for your help!