# PHP Form Redirect Based Off of Drop Down Selection

Tags: php, forms, redirect

This relates to a previous question I had asked about [filling out a php form and using those answers to populate a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605471/make-a-form-in-php-that-saves-information-a-user-gives-and-plugs-it-into-a-anoth). When finished filling out the form, I want to determine what page it goes to after you submit the form by a dropdown you choose while filling out the form.

For example, you type in:

Your Name

Email

Phone Number

Then from a drop down you'd pick "Page 3".

Then hit submit.

I would need it then to redirect you to "Page 3" because that's the one you chose in the drop down. I know this should be simple, I just can't seem to figure out how to do it. Thank you in advance to all that help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the script your form submits to:

```
if ($_POST['dropdown-name'] == 'Page 3') {
    header("Location: page3.php");
} else if ($_POST['dropdown-name'] == 'Page 4') {
    header("Location: page4.php");
} // ... etc
```

~

```
$pages = array('Page 1' => 'page1.php', 'Page 2' => 'page2.php', 'Page 3' => 'page3.php');

if (array_key_exists($_POST['dropdown-name'], $pages)) {
    header("Location: " . $pages[$_POST['dropdown-name']]);
} else {
    echo "Error processing form"; // submitted form value wasn't in your array, perhaps a hack attempt
}
```

Comment: You would just keep putting "else if" for every new page?

Comment: Unless you have a huge number of pages, yes. If you have too many, you can put them in an array and compare the form data to the array.

Comment: Well I essentially need it to work like this answer that you gave, but there will be a lot of pages. How would I handle putting them into an array?

Comment: I can't put that much code in a comment, so I edited my answer

Comment: Lastly, how would I plug this into a form? Sorry to need it spelled out for me, php's definitely not my specialty.

Comment: Would 'Page 1' be <option value="Page 1">Page 1</option>?

Comment: Yes, it can be whatever you want as long as you use the same values in the <option> tag and the keys in the array.

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OnChangeForm()
{
    var e = document.getElementById("changeFormAct");
    var strType = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    if(strType == '1')
    {
        document.myform.action ="football.html";   // here myform is the name of theform
    }
    else
    if(strType == '2')
    {
        document.myform.action ="cricket.html";
    }
    else
    if(strType == '3')
    {
        document.myform.action ="hockey.html";
    }
    else
    if(strType == '4')
    {
        document.myform.action ="tennis.html";
    }
    return true;
}
</script>

<select onchange="OnChangeForm" id="changeFormAct">
    <option value="1">Football</option>
    <option value="2">Cricket</option>
    <option value="3">Hockey</option>
    <option value="4">Tennis</option>
</select>
```