# I need to have a form be filled out, go to a page chosen in a drop down then use the other info from the form to populate the chosen page

Tags: php, forms, redirect, populate

I have asked two previous questions for [taking info put into a form and using it to populate a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605471/make-a-form-in-php-that-saves-information-a-user-gives-and-plugs-it-into-a-anoth), and one to [redirect you to a page when you submit the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771899/php-form-redirect-based-off-of-drop-down-selection) based off of what you choose in the forms drop down. Now I need these two things to both work for the same form.

The code for taking the info from the form and using it to populae the next page is:

```
<?php
$firstname = $_GET['personsName'];
echo "My Name is" .$firstname;
?>
```

And the form would look like this:

```
<form action="letter.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="personsName"></input>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

The code for selecting a page is:

```
$pages = array('Page 1' => 'page1.php', 'Page 2' => 'page2.php', 'Page 3' => 'page3.php');

if (array_key_exists($_POST['dropdown-name'], $pages)) {
header("Location: " . $pages[$_POST['dropdown-name']]);
} else {
echo "Error processing form"; // submitted form value wasn't in your array, perhaps a hack attempt
}
```

I need for both of these to work for the same form, I just haven't been able to figure it out. What I tried was:

```
<form action="<?=$pages?>" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name" /><br />
<select name="letter">

<option value="Page 1">
Page 1
</option>

<option value="Page 2">
Page 2
</option>

<option value="Page 3">
Page 3
</option>

</select>
<input type="submit" value"Print" />
</form>
```

This is obviously wrong. I need this form to take the info put into it, redirect to the page chosen, then populate the page with the other info inputted into the form. The problem is I have no idea how to get the answers I already have together. Thank you to all that help!

Current code is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function UpdateFormAction(){
alert('Launched event handler');
var form = document.getElementById('MyForm');
var list = document.getElementById('PageList');
alert('List item numer ' + list.selectedIndex);
var desiredAction = list.options[list.selectedIndex].value
alert('Desired action set to ' + desiredAction);
form.action = desiredAction;
});
</script>
```

Form is:

```
<form id="MyForm" action="letter.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name" /><br />
<select id="PageList" name="letter" onchange="UpdateFormAction();">

<option value="letter.php">Page 1</option>
<option value="letter2.php">Page 2</option>
<option value="letter3.php">Page 3</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value"Print" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're losing the data sent to the server when you do the redirect.

Basically, you've got 3 options:

- Store the data on the client using a cookie or similar (A lot of overhead for something simple)
- Store the data server-side in a session or similar (even more overhead)
- Pass the data through the URL you're redirecting to...

So something like:

```
if (array_key_exists($_POST['dropdown-name'], $pages)) {
    header("Location: " . $pages[$_POST['dropdown-name']] . "?personsName=" urlencode($_POST['name']));
} else {
    //Blah
}
```

Which seems to be the best answer for your simple example. If there's a LOT of data or it's more complex, consider using one of the other 2 option above

NB: On the form you've called the variable `name`, on the pae receiving it, you've called it `personsName` - note the mapping from one to the other in the URL.

Javascript solution (tested):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SO Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function UpdateFormAction(){
            var form = document.getElementById('MyForm');
            var list = document.getElementById('PageList');
            var desiredAction = list.options[list.selectedIndex].value
            form.action = desiredAction;
            document.getElementById('Target').innerHTML = 'Form action set to: ' + desiredAction;
        }
    </script>

    <form id="MyForm" action="letter.php" method="POST">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
        Page: <select id="PageList" name="letter" onchange="UpdateFormAction();">
            <option value="letter.php">Page 1</option>
            <option value="letter2.php">Page 2</option>
            <option value="letter3.php">Page 3</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Print" /><br/>
        <span id="Target">Form action unmodified</span>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the actual form I'd be getting 10 pieces of information to populate the redirected page. Is that too much to use this method?

Comment: There's a limit on how long URLs can be (1024 characters for IE6, at least 4096 for all later/more modern browsers if I remember correctly) so it will depend on what the data is. simple input fields should be fine but large textareas could be a problem.

Comment: oh and of course, you could use some simple javascript so that when the drop-down is changed, the `action` of the form changes to the appropriate page - so then there's no PHP step in the middle and you submit directly to the desired page.

Comment: That would be perfect, the javascript solution! Can you give me a quick example?

Comment: And I've just refactored it into a function for better readability.

Comment: Wait, when I tested it out it just does the action that's already there, the javascript didn't switch the action to the one I chose.

Comment: Most likely there's a typo in the JS which isn't being displayed. I've added some alerts to the code (make sure you remove them asap!). You should get an alert to say the method has fired, another when it's determined the selected value in the list and a final one when it's about to set the new page. Let me know what alerts you see. Also, depending on the browser you're using, see if you can find the JS error messages. In IE, it's usually an exclamation mark in the bottom bar of the main window

Comment: Alright, well I started to figure it out some but I'm still not getting it. At first it wasn't even loading the alerts and I figured out it was the way the functions was starting. Had to be $(function UpdateFormAction()... etc. Then the alerts come up. But the last alert is shown before I even submit the form. The alert says "desired action set to page1.php" before I choose anything from the dropdown. Could it be because the dropdown is on page1.php by default, then the script just takes that and doesn't wait until the form is actually submitted before processing the info?

Comment: I think you're getting a little confused - `$( ` is a syntax used primarily by jQuery, a Javascript library. It's not required but is handy. The onchange event may be firing when the page loads - The alerts should show every time you change the drop-down list, not whent he form is submitted. Can you post your current code at the end of the question?

Comment: It wasn't doing anything though at first, until I added the $( into it. I know it's just for jquery but just tried it out and it got it to start showing the alerts. Idk, lol. I do load jquery into the page, could that be interfering with the javascript? And all the alerts come up right when I load the page. None come up when I change the dropdown.

Comment: I've edited my code to be fully tested. If you copy/paste it into a new file and open it in a browser, it works perfectly. If there are problems when you do the same on the site, something else is interfering but without seeing the full output from your page, I can't begin to guess what it might be.

Comment: We have lift off. I tested multiple pages, it works great! Thank you for helping me through it! I took out the call for jquery, I think that might've been causing an issue for some reason? I put everything in exactly as you have it here and it works perfectly.

Comment: exactly so - $() was being executed when the document finished loading so it could evaluate jQuery calls - you were effectively tying your code into `document.onload` (well, not quite - but close enough)